# how to fix the code that refuses to show the result?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I'm trying to reverse the elements of an array.My code has no compiling      error or run time error , but still it refuses to show the result.

I've tried every possible alternate methods according to my knowledge.

```
class mark25 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[] = {
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5
        };
        int len = arr.length;
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[len - 1];
                arr[len - 1] = temp;
                if (i > len - 1) {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }

        }
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the code to show  reversed order of the the array "arr".

Answer (score 0):

It is because, your code is "stuck in infinite loop"

Your `if(i>len-1)` condition is in contradiction with the condition for your for-loop condition `i<len-1`. So, flag variable never gets the value `FALSE` and thus never terminates

Besides that, there are couple other mistakes as well.

In your for-loop, your are interchanging the value of index i with index len-1, But value of len variable is not getting changed.

Here is a solution, with some changes:

- You do not need to have a nested loop.
- You will have to decrement the value of len after each interchange of
  values.

---

```
class mark25 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[] = {
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5
        };
        int len = arr.length;
        boolean flag = true;
        int i = 0;
        while (flag) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[len - 1];
            arr[len - 1] = temp;
            len--;
            i++;
            if (i > len - 1) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = {5,0,6,7,8};    
ArrayUtils.reverse(arr);   
for(int i =0 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

This is another approach for reversing an array.For using ArrayUtils download commons.lang3.jar and add it to your build path.Hope it helps.